# Angular 2 - Is not a constructor error

Tags: angular, constructor, model

I'm trying to create an instance of a class. However I've been getting this error which I can't solve:

> models.MyTimeDefinition is not a constructor

My **models.MyTimeDefinition**

```
Import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class MyTimeDefinition {
    RequestCodes: Array<RequestCodes>;
    BalanceCodes: Array<BalanceCodes>;

    Description: {
        SelectedLanguage: number,
        Values: any
    };

    ID: number;
    DescriptionID: number;

    Info: {
        CreationUser: string,
        CreationDate: string,
        LastChangedUser: string,
        LastChangedDate: string,
        Info: string
    };

    IsDataLoaded: boolean;
    TypeName: string;


    constructor(userLanguage: number, languages: any) {
        this.RequestCodes = [];
        this.BalanceCodes = [];
        this.ID = 0;
        this.DescriptionID = 0;
        this.Info = { CreationUser: null, CreationDate: null, LastChangedUser: null, LastChangedDate: null, Info: null };
        this.Description = { SelectedLanguage: userLanguage, Values: null };
        this.TypeName = "MyTimeDefinitionDetailViewModel";
    }
}
```

Here's the **call** I create to run the constructor:

```
public createNewMyTimeDefinition() {
this.definitionDetails = new models.MyTimeDefinition(this.definitionData.UserLanguage, this.definitionData.Languages);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why do you think it is? Where does `models` come from`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `this.definitionDetails = new MyTimeDefinition(...)`?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/RXUm7nxgA0cJIRtVraOt?p=preview

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `import * as models from "../models/models";`

Comment: Looks like a problem with the import.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, no the import is fine, I can use the interface, or when I create a type of like `public definitionDetails: models.MyTimeDefinition;` it's just when I create a new instance of the class that it gives me this error

Comment: But the Plunker creates an instance of your class just fine.